# How can I import this React package using RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, commonjs

There is a package called `formsy-react` that looks like it was made to be imported using CommonJS (see code here: https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/release/formsy-react.js) but I'm having trouble getting it to work with RequireJS.

Specifically I try

```
require(['formsy-react.js'], function (Formsy) { console.log(Formsy) });
```

but `Formsy` is not defined. I'm new to RequireJS so I'm just not sure what to do here. Is there any best practices to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to React, unless you *have* to use require.js, it's strongly recommended to use commonjs approaches, with browserify or webpack, to get your code up and running.

If you absolutely have to use require.js, you can write a require wrapper around https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/build/formsy-react.js, but it's going to be clunky.

Comment: Why is it strongly recommended to use commonjs?

Comment: Primariy because React is "taught" by the React team and website using commonjs syntax, and the currently best bundlers for that are Browserify (pretty much "the" bundler in node land) and Webpack (newer, but advocated and used by the React and Flux teams). In terms of why one would use them instead of require.js when it does a job just fine, Browserify was born mostly to addresses deficiencies in Require.js, which it did really well, and Webpack was born to address the problems with bundling inside a much larger automation taskset.